# Does the Password reset disk created for windows work if the password is changed after creating it?

Tags: windows, passwords, password-recovery

Does the windows password recovery disk work, if the password for which it is created is changed.

Comment: No, as the reset disk contains the password at the time of creation.

Comment: But if you forgot the password depending on what version of windows you are on its very easy to change.